# WCF Client-side object deserialize notification

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, .net-4.0

I have a WPF client application receiving objects via a reference to a remote WCF service.  The WCF service references were generated via Visual Studio's 'Add Service Reference...'.

I would like to execute a piece of code each time an object received/deserialized from the WCF service. The object needs to already be deserialized so I can read properties/call methods on it.  This solution would be global and not something I need to add to every WCF service call.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Are you looking for code samples where someone has done this?  Can you be more specific in what your intention is?

Comment: I wanted to make the question as generic as possible. I'm looking for guidance on where I can hook into the WCF workflow (an attribute somewhere? behaviors?) Specifically, I want to subscribe to the INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged event of each object that enters the system so I can determine if any incoming objects have been modified by the user.

Comment: I see.  take a look at Mike's answer...it might be just what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with Mike's initial response I was able to come up with the following solution.

**Background**

1. Client pulls data from the server, over a WCF service.
2. The WCF service reference is generated by Visual Studio with "reuse types in referenced assemblies" so no WCF proxy manipulation can be done.
3. A property on the Client side app needs to be modified when any property, on any of the objects received from WCF has changed (these objects implement INotifyPropertyChanged)

**Forewarning**

I understand that this breaks some object oriented and responsibility rules, however the solution is so short, so easy, and fits my current and anticipated future needs so it is what I went with.  This solution is less practical when there is significant logic that needs to occur on each client-side deserialization.

```
[DataContract]
public class DataTransferObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [OnDeserialized]
    public void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
    {
        dynamic app = Application.Current;
        if(app != null) //Prevents execution on server-side.  This code is meant to only execute at the client
        {
            PropertyChanged += (sender, args) =>
                                   {
                                       app.IsAnythingDirty = true;
                                   };
        }
    }
}
```

**The keys**

1. The reason this works is the dynamic keyword.  You have to use the
   dynamic keyword because the project containing the DTO cannot reference the
   UI project due to a circular reference.  If it can't reference the UI project the compiler does not know about the IsAnythingDirty boolean.
2. Checking whether Application.Current is null ensures that the code will only run on the client-side, not the server-side.

Comment: Looks like a good, pragmatic solution to me. If you self-hosted the service, would Application.Current still be null?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the OnDeserialized attribute:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializedattribute.aspx

Comment: This is close to what I am looking for but would require the code to be placed in the Type that is being sent over the wire (I'm using "reuse types in referenced assemblies").  If the code is in this shared code it does not have access to any information within my WPF/client application.

Comment: Are you in control of the service code as well as the client? If you are, you could place the data transfer objects (and the contract) in their own assembly and reference it directly on the client rather than use Add Service Reference in Visual Studio. You could use that to generate the client config (this is often a bit error prone). but then use ChannelFactory with the contract type in the referenced assembly.

Comment: Or if you don't have access to the service code, you could use add service reference to generate the proxy classes and then paste the code into your own classes and add the relevent methods to handle the deserialization events.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use the proxy generation and tweak the proxy because I need to be able to accept an object from service1 and send it back through service2 (thus the "reuse types" option)

Comment: I see. I guess you could define an interface that the shared code references and have that implemented within the WPF client and maybe use an IoC pattern to inject the type from the client into the shared code but its all getting a bit messy...

Comment: Last suggestion. you could create a custom serializer/deserializer:
http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/03/07/xmlserializer-vs-datacontractserializer-serialization-in-wcf/